# How can I query a list of parts so that I can easily compare parts from many different groups? (pivot table?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that tracks information about, (for this example lets say) cars. Each entry contains a description about a certain part on the car. So for example this is what a snippet of the table data looks like:

```
+-----+-----------+--------------+-------------+
| ID  | ModelName | PartCategory | Description |
+-----+-----------+--------------+-------------+
|   1 | name1     | category1    | blah blah   |
|   2 | name1     | category2    | blah blah   |
|   3 | name2     | category2    | blah blah   |
|   4 | name2     | category3    | blah blah   |
|   5 | name2     | category4    | blah blah   |
| ... | ...       | ...          | ...         |
+-----+-----------+--------------+-------------+
```

Is there any clever way to query the data so that I could more easily compare the data of multiple models at the same time? Basically I want to compare part categories of multiple cars at once. Not every car has a record for every part category though, so I would like nulls in those cases. I'm trying to make something that looks like this:

```
+-----------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
| category  | name1 | name2  | name3  | ... |
+-----------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
| category1 | Value | Value  | Value  | ... |
| category2 | Value | Value  | Value  | ... |
| category3 | Value | (null) | Value  | ... |
| category4 | Value | Value  | (null) | ... |
+-----------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
(Is this what you would call a table pivot?)
```

Or is this schema bad for this purpose in the first place? Comparing car models is the main objective of this application so if the table structure in the 1st snipped seems like a bad idea right off the bat, I would be open to a different model.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different functionality here.)

Comment: I am currently using MYSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first table doesn't look quite right as that would end up in creating redundant data.
Alternate Data model - Create 3 tables with datamodel as below to populate the data.

1. **Table 1**

   ```
   ┌───────────────────┬──────────────┬─────────────────┐
   │ Table_Name        │ Model_Config │                 │
   ├───────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────┤
   │ Column_name       │ Data_type    │ Constraint      │
   ├───────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────┤
   │ Model_Id          │ number(5)    │ PK              │
   ├───────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────┤
   │ Model_Name        │ varchar2(50) │                 │
   └───────────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────┘
   ```
2. **Table 2**

   ```
   ┌───────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
   │ Table_Name        │ PartCategory_Config            │
   ├───────────────────┼──────────────┬─────────────────┤
   │ Column_name       │ Data_type    │ Constraint      │
   ├───────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────┤
   │ PartCategory_Id   │ number(5)    │ PK              │
   ├───────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────┤
   │ PartCategory_Name │ varchar2(50) │                 │
   └───────────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────┘
   ```
3. **Table 3**

   ```
   ┌───────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
   │ Table_Name        │ Model_partCategory_link        │
   ├───────────────────┼──────────────┬─────────────────┤
   │ Column_name       │ Data_type    │ Constraint      │
   ├───────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────┤
   │ Model_Id          │ number(5)    │                 │
   ├───────────────────┼──────────────┤                 │
   │ PartCategory_Id   │ number(5)    │  Composite_PK   │
   └───────────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────┘
   ```

I have uploaded the query to the dbfiddle link below for the existing datamodel as per your table as well as query for suggested datamodel changes. Could you check below link for the solution and see if this works for you.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c207dd2b71545ed787db0fb7ef65800a